# Odoo 10 Developer mode and developer mode with assets

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, debug-mode

I'm new on Odoo v10.  I'm using the debug mode with URL.  But on the settings menu there is links to activate developer mode.  I want to ask, 
What is the difference between "Activate the developer mode"  and "Activate developer mode ( with asset)"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Debug mode (most of the time used by Administrator)**
With this mode you can unable some advance features/options in odoo. so if you open odoo with debug mode you will see some extra menus, extra fields to more advance configuration.

**Debug with assets mode (most of the time used by developers)**
It enables all features from normal debug plus some extra. Odoo internally use assets bundles to improve performance which internal merge+minifies all static assets like css and JavaScript. So debug with assets will use actual css and javascript files instead of minifying/merging css and js files. This mode will reduce performance but it will give you proper error message in console if you are doing some JavaScript changes in odoo

**Debug with assets mode (tests assets)**
According to [this](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/14.0/general/developer_mode/activate.html#:%7E:text=Activate%20the%20developer%20mode%20%28with%20tests%20assets%29), starting from Odoo 13 (also available in Odoo 14), we have a new debug mode. This mode is mostly for developers & testers.

You can use this [**chrome plugin**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/odoo-debug/hmdmhilocobgohohpdpolmibjklfgkbi) to quick switch between all those modes.

Comment: Thanks for your time

Comment: Thanks @parth-gajjar
Its really helpful.